# PHP-GTK problem with GtkBuilder

Tags: php-gtk

Hello guys I am using Glade 3.6.7 with PHP-GTK on Ubuntu lucid lynx to create some application. During experimenting I got an error when I use GtkBuilder as Project file format in glade when i tried to execute a very simple php script to make sure it works.

```
<?php
$glade = new GladeXML("test.glade");
Gtk::main();
?>
```

I got the following error

```
varoom@varoom-laptop:~/public_html/gtk$ php gtk.php

(gtk.php:4800): libglade-WARNING **: Expected <glade-interface>.  Got <interface>.

(gtk.php:4800): libglade-WARNING **: did not finish in PARSER_FINISH state
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PhpGtkConstructException' with message 'could not construct GladeXML object' in /home/varoom/public_html/gtk/gtk.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /home/varoom/public_html/gtk/gtk.php(3): GladeXML->__construct('test.glade')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/varoom/public_html/gtk/gtk.php on line 3
```

Please note that i removed some comments from the php file so line numbers are not reliable though i don't have any code rather than what i put here.

When I choose Libglade as project file format everything goes well and the test runs successfully but there are some widgets disabled like TextBuffer !

So how can I use GtkBuilder with the extra widgets right there ?

Answer (score 1):

you should have to save your glade gui with the extension "libglade" in the save dialog - not all gtk builders have this function -> try out glade 3.8.5 !

greetz robert